# Azure SQL Server SUM query times out randomly

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

We have relatively-high load SQL database with accounting information, which is hosted on Azure cloud. To calculate balance of user account(s) we sum all ins and outs every time (`entry` table). I know we could do that differently, but current solution works quite well in absolute majority of cases and HTTP request for getting balance takes ~134 ms on average (and that includes much more than just the problematic query) despite `entry` table contains hundreds of billions of rows (we have many accounts and not that much operations on each).

Our **SQL** (slightly beautified after NHibernate - removed column and table aliases):

```
select AccountId, cast(sum(Amount) as DECIMAL(19,5)) as Balance
from entry
where  not (Locked=1) and (AccountId in (@p0))
group by AccountId
```

Execution plan of fast-executing query (not sure if it is helpful):
[image]
So query uses index which include AccountId, Locked and two more columns after that.

**Usually** it executes in less than **100ms**, but sometimes (**1 in ~1000 requests**) hangs for **30+ seconds** and fails on timeout.

I've tried to find deadlocks using `sp_who2` stored procedure, but nothing was found - it didn't show any blocked queries even though I tried it many times and exceptions were constantly being thrown during this time.

Interestingly, we have hundreds of requests of this kind per minute, but **failures occur one by one, so intervals between exceptions are at least 30s** and are multiplies of 30 (30, 60, 90, 120 seconds - 30 and 60 are the most common). I cannot explain this, but I suppose there is some job I don't know about, which is running as single-thread and blocking particular accounts. But how can I find it?

Comment: Did you check the amounts always I mean there could be issue with the data amount at some point like if sum for some amount fails then therafter it cant be stopped as the leftover data even if its correct to sum will not work

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, Every row has amount (NOT NULL) and there is certainly no overflow issue there. Same query for same account executes fine just before the problem and also after the problemmatic request fails.

Comment: Yeah, the 30-second regularity speaks to some kind of scheduled task...something that takes some kind of escalating lock on `entry`. Might not be dml at all...maybe look for some kind of partition maintenance? I'm guessing you've got that monster partitioned. Bad guess?

Comment: @Clay, some update for the problem: we found one deadlock reason (using SQL Server deadlock analysis) - a query not using FOR UDPATE clause. Also redirected GetBalance queries to replica DB. At first sight it appears 60-second intervals between exceptions appear more often now, but still the number of exceptions is very high and we don't see any more deadlocks...
We do not have partitioning configured - DB size it ~500 GB and while it's definitely huge, most of requests are fast enough.